# How to invoke ivy-immediate-done in emacs prelude

Tags: ivy, prelude

I recently installed the prelude distribution of emacs, with minimal customizations. I want to invoke `ivy-immediate-done`

> C-M-j (ivy-immediate-done) - exit with the current action, calling it on the current input instead of the current candidate. This is useful especially when creating new files or directories - often the input will match an existing file, which you don’t want to select.

but in my config C-M-j is set to default-indent-new-line

> C-M-j runs the command default-indent-new-line (found in global-map),
> which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

So far I've tried running

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [ivy-immediate-done] "C-M-j")
```

to rebind C-M-j in the minibuffer. That didn't work.